# Changing from a free to a paid app

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an Android app and added it as a beta app to the play store. Then I discovered that my beta testers would have to buy the app, so I changed it to free (oops). I now understand that I can't change a free app to a paid app and that I need to add a new app to the developer console.

However, when I try to add a new app, the Google Developer Console reports that the title has already been used (obviously). But that's the name I need (i.e., I have the same-named app available on other platforms). What should I do? If I delete the existing (beta) app will it let me reuse the name? I don't want to try doing this without knowing, because I suspect I'll break the versions that are being used by my beta testers.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to use a different package name for your paid version and you could try to rename the free beta version and see if you can then use the intended name for the paid one.

Comment: Perfect, Nobu, renaming the beta version worked. Do you want to add your answer as a reply (rather than a comment) and I'll mark it as the answer? Otherwise I'll answer my own question.

Comment: Oh, that takes me by surprise myself! :-D Sure, I'll post my comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use a different package name for your paid version. Rename the free beta version and then use the intended name for the paid one.